# Chrome bug related to .naturalWidth?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, input

It seems that the below code randomly produces `aImg.naturalWidth` either the real width of the picture or `0`. Is it a Chrome 70.0.3538.67 for Linux bug?

If it is not a bug, how to make it work right (not to return `0`)?

```
function handleImageFile(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    if (file.type != 'image/jpeg') continue;

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.file = file;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
      return function(e) {
        $('#newPictureContainer').css('display', 'block');
        document.getElementById('newPicture').appendChild(img);
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
        if (aImg.naturalWidth >= 300 || aImg.naturalHeight >= 300) {
          if (aImg.naturalWidth <= aImg.naturalHeight)
              aImg.width = 300;
          else
              aImg.height = 300;
          $('#selectPicture').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
          $('#selectPicture [type=file]').val("");
          alert("The smallest side of the picture should be at least 300 pixels.");
        }
      };
    })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}


  <div id="selectPicture" style="display:block">
    <input type="file" name="imageUpload" onchange="handleImageFile(this.files)"/>
  </div>
  <div id="newPictureContainer" style="display:none">
    <span id="newPicture"></span>
    <img src="/include/javascript/israelinfo/multiuploader/images/cross-small.gif"
          width="16" height="16" title="Удалить" alt="Delete" class="MUdelete"
          onclick="closePicture()">
  </div>
```

Comment: does it load (you can see it network > img tab) when it returns 0 ?

Comment: I suspect you're reading the image's natural width before it's finished loading. I'm more inclined to think that that is the case as opposed to it being a chrome bug.

Comment: Let your page load, then run the contents of the function in a console (long after the DOM is ready), that'll tell you whether it's a timing issue.

Comment: @line88 Yes, it _is_ displayed even in the case when it return 0

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I have almost no doubt that it is a timing issue. But it is called inside `onload`. By the very essence of this event, it must be loaded while handling this event. So I suspect it is Chrome bug

Comment: No, _something_ must be loaded while handling this event, not necessarily the image. You're handling the `onload` of the `FileReader`. Also, you're invoking it (`(img)`). Try handling the onload event of the img, see if that works. I don't think this is a chrome bug, especially since you're getting very inconsistent results, it feels like a bit of a race-condition thing.

Comment: in `img.onload` essentialy when you are applying `src` you are doing it after declaring `img.onload` function, may be this is the case here too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JᴀʏMᴇᴇ gave an answer:

I must access `.naturalWidth` in a handler of `onload` of the image not one of `FileReader`.

I mistakenly assumed that the image is loaded immediately after assigning a `data:` URL to `.src`. It seems not to be the case.